# VSTS Azure DevOps : Trying to Build and save only certain folders but everything from Project TFS Folder is getting built and deployed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to build and publish certain folders of a project and deploy them to remote server using Azure DevOps. My Copy files task and Archive copies everything from TFS instead of the content I want to build and deploy.
The last two screenshots display the Build folder getting published and the last one is the folder which is supposed to be Published.

[image: Build task]

[image: Copy Files Task]

[image: Archive Files Task]

[image: Publish Task]

[image: Published Folder]

[image: Supposed to be Published]

Comment: Your copied files seems to be accurate to your `contents` setting on `Copy Task`. What exactly do you expect to have copied?

Comment: I dont want folders like Controllers,App_Start and folders containing cs files to be copied as we do not deploy the .cs files.

Comment: I know what you don't want to, but what do you want to copy? Is there one folder which you want to deploy? Can you name it?

Comment: The last screenshot displays the folders I intend to copy. While the last but one screenshot is from the Publish folders which are getting copied

Comment: Maybe it worth to set Copy To Output Directory flag to the folders you want to publish in VS and then just apply Copy Files to your /bin/ directory only.